# get cookies with tornado StaticFileHandler

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, tornado

I want to get the user's session cookie when he's fetching some js static file:

```
class StaticFileHandler(web.StaticFileHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, path):
        print ('got JS request from %s' % self.request.remote_ip)
        print ('request.cookies : %s' % self.request.cookies)
        super(StaticFileHandler, self).get(path)
```

However, The cookies are always `None`, even though I can see in the browser it has the session cookie set.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it impossible to fetch cookies when serving a static file like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tornado documentation  warns against overriding the StaticFileHandler get method:  http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler

"Subclasses should only override methods discussed in this section; overriding other methods is error-prone. Overriding StaticFileHandler.get is particularly problematic due to the tight coupling with compute_etag and other methods."

I would suggest that you instead try overriding the `get_content` method of the StaticFileHandler class:

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.get_content

Comment: thanks. I'm not really changing anything in the get method, just adding two or three lines of logic and calling the original get, so I don't see how this could be problematic. also, I eventually got around this problem by setting the cookie as a url parameter.